# Polygon automatcally adjust to its above polygon

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio

I'm making a Windows Desktop Application that have drag and drop functionality.
I'm using Polygon (And Images later) Shapes for drag and drop. The drag and drop functionality works fine but I want that if user drag any shape from the panel and when he drag other shape then the second shape automatically fix with first shape. 
You'll understand it by take a look at below screenshots.

**It is the Screen Shot of what happens when I drag Shapes**

When user drop the polygon near the other polygon it will automatically adjust itself, if the same polygon drop in other area of canvas than a error will show to the user.

[image]

**Here is my XAML Code**

```
<Window x:Class="Images.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Images"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800">
    <DockPanel 
        VerticalAlignment="Stretch" 
        Height="Auto">

        <DockPanel 
            HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" 
            VerticalAlignment="Stretch" 
            Height="Auto" 
            MinWidth="400"
            Margin="10">

            <GroupBox 
                DockPanel.Dock="Left" 
                Width="350" 
                Background="Aqua"
                VerticalAlignment="Stretch" 
                VerticalContentAlignment="Stretch" 
                Height="Auto">
                <WrapPanel Margin="0,10,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top">
                    <Button Name="control" Content="Control" Height="30" Background="BlueViolet" Margin="5" Width="100"/>
                    <Button Name="motion" Content="Motion" Width="100" Margin="5" Background="Green" Height="30"/>
                    <Button Name="variable" Content="Variable" Width="100" Margin="5" Background="SeaGreen" Height="30"/>
                    <Button Name="sensor" Content="Sensor" Width="100" Margin="5" Background="OrangeRed" Height="30"/>
                    <Button Name="lcd" Content="LCD" Width="100" Margin="5" Height="30" Background="PaleVioletRed"/>
                    <Button Name="function" Content="Function" Width="100" Margin="5" Height="30" Background="Salmon"/>

                    <StackPanel Name="heaading" Width="350">
                        <TextBlock Name="controlName" TextAlignment="Center" Text="Controls"/>
                    </StackPanel>
                    <StackPanel Name="userControls" Orientation="Vertical">
                        <!--  Users Controls Items Goes Here -->
                        <Polygon Name="startProgram" Points="80,10, 80, 80, 135,80, 135, 45, 205, 45, 205, 80, 260, 80, 260,10" Fill="Chocolate" Stroke="Black" StrokeThickness="2" MouseLeftButtonDown="shape_MouseLeftButtonDown" />
                        <Polygon Name="endProgram" Fill="BlueViolet"  Points="80,40, 80,80, 260,80, 260,40, 200,40, 200,10, 140,10,140,40"  Stroke="Black" StrokeThickness="2" MouseLeftButtonDown="shape_MouseLeftButtonDown" />
                    </StackPanel>
                </WrapPanel>

            </GroupBox>

            <!-- Change this to Canvas for work later -->
            <Canvas x:Name="dropArea" DockPanel.Dock="Right" Margin="10" Background="#FF9760BF" Width="Auto" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" AllowDrop="True" Drop="dropArea_Drop">

            </Canvas>
        </DockPanel>
    </DockPanel>
</Window>
```

**Here is my CS code**

```
namespace Images
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void dropArea_Drop(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
        {
            var shape = e.Data.GetData(typeof(Polygon)) as Polygon;
            Console.WriteLine("Polygon Name : " + shape.Name);
            Polygon myPolygon = new Polygon();
            myPolygon.Stroke = shape.Stroke;
            myPolygon.Fill = shape.Fill;
            myPolygon.StrokeThickness = 2;
            Canvas.SetTop(myPolygon, e.GetPosition(dropArea).Y);

            myPolygon.Points = shape.Points;
            dropArea.Children.Add(myPolygon);
            myPolygon.MouseRightButtonDown += new MouseButtonEventHandler(dragged_ShapeMouseDown);
        }

        private void dragged_ShapeMouseDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
        {
             //Show Options to Delete or set Value to current Polygon
        }

    private void shape_MouseLeftButtonDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
        {
            Polygon shape = e.Source as Polygon;
            DragDrop.DoDragDrop(shape, shape, DragDropEffects.Copy);
        }
    }
}
```

**Problem**

1. I'm using Canvas.setTop because without setting it my polygon show over the first.
2. Here I'm setting the polygon that fix with its above polygon but it can be left or right also as shown in below screenshot.

[image]

Comment: Good job with a well written quesiton. However, what you're asking isn't simple enough to fit in a single answer. What you want to achieve is polygon snapping. To do that you need to go through some form of collision detection. Clipper is a nuget library that appears to have the capability you need but documentation is lacking and will require trial & error. (I'm sure there are other possibilities but none are simple and this was the first one that popped up in my search)

Comment: @Maverik, Thanks for your suggestion, I know this isn't simple :) but I'll check clipper library :)

Comment: Are they always going to approach from across fixed x or y co-ordinates? IE top to bottom, side to side? And. Will the shapes always fit?  Also is there a fixed pattern to your shapes?  Could you add a set x and y distance to the top left of your shape and hit test it? You can do hittesting px by px to see whether they're inside  a geometry. This is  quite expensive so you'd only want to do it once ideally. Or along one line a few times otherwise.

Comment: Calculating an angle and using a bresenham algorithm to work out which px are along the line described by that angle is possible but you'd want just one line of px. Bresenham is very fast but hit testing is sloooooow. Ideally you want to calculate a point and just do that once.

Comment: Another approach which would speed things up a LOT would be to translate the position of your target shape into a 2d array of true/false. With an integer X and Y translating directly to position on the canvas. You can then ditch hit testing and use something like a bresenham algorithm to check co-ordinates. That is easily fast enough to check for a real time collision along one specific line.

Comment: @Andy, Thanks for giving these options, I'll try them. :)

Answer (score 1):

**SOLUTION**

For Deleting shape

```
myPolygon.MouseLeftButtonUp += new MouseButtonEventHandler(dragged_ShapeMouseDown);

private void dragged_ShapeMouseDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
     if (dropArea.Children.Count > 0)
         dropArea.Children.Remove(sender as Polygon);
}
```

Comment: But what about 2 problem how can i achieve that :)

Comment: I looked into those as well. Those are bit of time consuming. I will post solutions if I get some.

Comment: Okk  Thanks Buddy.

Comment: Gaurang Dave, Did you get the solution?

Comment: Why and who did downvote?  Still I am not getting the solution.

Answer (score 1):

Sacha Barber has got very nice article that describe exactly what you are trying to do i think...4 steps articles up to MVVM ! have a look these [step1](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/22952/WPF-Diagram-Designer-Part-1) and 
[step2](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/22952/WPF-Diagram-Designer-Part-2), [step3](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/22952/WPF-Diagram-Designer-Part-3), [step4](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/22952/WPF-Diagram-Designer-Part-4) - I also used it in my own project [ArchX](https://github.com/TheCamel/ArchX)

well, i think everything is there in my code : during onmove test the result and change the cursor. ondragend : use a HitHelper to determine where you release the mouse and return the shape his tested - then adjust the shape of the polygon regarding the hit result  : below sample code - [GuideLineManager](https://github.com/TheCamel/ArchX/blob/master/ArchX.Controls/Guidelines/GuideLineManager.cs)

```
public Cursor HitTestGuide(Point p, RulerOrientation mode)
    {
        if (_Guides.Exists(g => (int)g.Info.Orientation == (int)mode && g.HitTest(p)))
        {
            return _Guides.First(g => (int)g.Info.Orientation == (int)mode && g.HitTest(p)).Cursor;

        }
        return Cursors.Arrow;
    }
```

and the onDragEnd, call to get the hit tested object

```
public Guideline GetSnapGuide(Point hitPoint)

    {

        foreach (Guideline gl in Guides)
        {
            if (!gl.IsDisplayed) continue;
            if (gl.Info.IsSnap && !gl.Info.IsMoving)

                if (gl.IsOnGuide(hitPoint, _Container.dPicCapture))
                {
                    return gl;
                }
        }
        return null;
    }
```

Comment: I have checked it earlier. It is for drag and drop shapes from toolbox. I have done it but I want my canvas items automatically connect with each other. Please check my question

Comment: Ok buddy, I'll check it